# Url rewrite for outbound rules causing infinite redirect on Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8

Tags: windows, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance running IIS 8.

We are hosting a .NET 4.0 website trying to use an outbound rewrite rule to fetch CDN assets.

The presence of the `outboundRules` tag in the `web.config` seems to throw the site into an endless redirect loop. The site performs perfectly without the `outboundRules` tag. I have included the actual rewrite rule we are using but even including the `outboundRules` tag with nothing in it can cause the site to end up non responsive.

We have confirmed that static compression is not enabled for the site which is what a few other posts around the web have referenced but that does not seem to resolve our situation.

```
<outboundRules>
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="ExcludeAXD">
      <add input="{URL}" pattern=".axd" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern=".asmx" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern=".ashx" negate="true" />
   </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
  <rule name="CDNRule" enabled="true" preCondition="ExcludeAXD" 
        stopProcessing="true">
    <match filterByTags="Img, Input, Script, Link" 
           pattern="(^.*?(?=/mymediafoldercontainingassets))(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}http://subdomain.mycdn.com{R:2}" />
  </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Do you have any inbound rules? I don't see anything very wrong or strange with what you've got there, having been doing something similar on IIS7.5 today. If it was a compression problem then you'd see a 500.52 error status. Might be an idea to (in another site for testing) create a simple static HTML file and then try the outbound rule on that to see if you can repro in a very basic test case.

Comment: A precondition that's wise to use is to make sure you're only attempting to replace where the response type is text/html: `<add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />`.

Comment: Thanks Kev,   This site was sitting on IIS 7.0 before we moved it with no issues.   This seems to only be happening once moving to IIS 8. We don't have any inbound rules for this site. The key thing that confuses me is the mere presence of the outboundrules tag is enough to cause the rewrite to go haywire.   Thanks for the help.